# Доступ к DLNA функциям Windows Media Player из кода

Tags: c#, c++, windows, mediaplayer

Как известно, стандартный Windows Media Player от Microsoft обладает полной функциональностью DLNA сервера, рендерера и контрольной точки. Притом, в сравнении с DLNA рендерерами, встроенными в телевизоры (smart TVs), set-top box-ы, и всевозможные китайские и некитайские HDMI-dongles, Media Player играет, **буквально говоря, все** (ну, в зависимости от кодеков, установленных на PC).

Мне бы хотелось получить, каким-то образом, доступ к интерфейсу(ам) DLNA, чтобы использовать COM-объект Windows Media Player в своем приложении, для обслуживания DLNA команд. Что я хочу получить в итоге: написать программу, которая, по команде DLNA "Play" будет проигрывать через Media Player медиа (картинку или видео) на полный экран, а по DLNA команде "Stop" - скрывать окно, то бишь эмулировать работу DLNA renderer-а smart TV.

Стандартный Windows Media Player прекрасно работает, но вот скрыть его окно никак не получится. То есть, без своей программы не обойтись.

Реализовывать свой UPnP DLNA интерфейс рендерера, честно говоря, неохота, хотелось бы re-use то, что давным-давно сделано в WMP.